# Can we retrieve the method body from .dll file?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have the requirement to retrieve the method body from a .dll file in C#. I'm using `System.Reflection` to retrieve the method names, parameters and properties etc. but didn't find a way the to retrieve the method body.

Please suggest me some an idea... :-)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Why do you need the method body?

Comment: Actually i am working out to track the changes that are made in the previous versions of .dll

Comment: So i need to get the method body where the change occured

Comment: Judging from your comments I'd say you need to start using a source code version control system (TFS, Git, whatever) instead of a way of reverse engineering source code from a DLL method. Unless perhaps the DLL is third party, but why would you want change tracking on that exactly..?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can retrieve the method body using [`MethodBase.GetMethodBody()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx), which gets you the raw IL, the local variables etc.

Obviously you'd need to load the assembly first (e.g. with `Assembly.Load`), then get the relevant type (`Assembly.GetType`), then find the method (`Type.GetMethod`), then get the method body.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reverse engineering tool like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). (Mind you, this might be illegal, depending on the situation.)

Also I'm not sure if this is a correct answer to the "in C#.Net" part of your question, as this is an external tool, not something you can easily do yourself from your own C# code. For that you'd need to interpret the IL you can get through reflection (see [Jon Skeets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447385/can-we-retrive-the-method-body-from-dll-file/3447468#3447468)) yourself

Comment: I just don't want ot use Reflector

Answer (score 0):

Well if you mean to retrieve the code of the method, unless it comes attached to the .dll, I don't think you can retrieve it.

By the other way, maybe you mean this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Hope it'll help you
regards